# Help finding a plugin - masonry type post grid

Tags: plugins, images, masonry

I would like to know if there exists a similar plugin to how this page lists its' products below the main banner: https://www.ycmcnc.com/en
Talking about this module: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HFlS.jpg

It seems to be like a masonry type grid with posts (and featured image of the post) as the blocks.

Is Essential Grid capable of this?

Would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: Can i just ask why the downvote? Is this not the place to ask such questions?

Comment: This forum is quite strict about allowed topics.  You're asking for an *opinion* re some *3rd party plugin*.  Up voted because OP is newb.

Comment: Ok, sorry if the topic is out of line. Will refrain in the future from asking these type of questions.